# Sympy how to extract the coefficients of polynomials with symbolic order

Tags: sympy

Consider the sympy expression

```
A,B,a,b,x=sympy.symbols("A,B,a,b,x")
expression=A*x**a*x**b +B*x**a*x**b
```

How to extract the coefficients and the order of the subsequent polynomial? i.e. `A` of `a+b` and `B` of `a+b`

```
expression.coeff(x)
0
```

since the sympy package itself does not recognize `x**a*x**b` as a polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```py
>>> expression.coeff(x**a*x**b)
A + B
```

If you aren't sure of how `x` appears you can get the coefficients in front of all `x`-dependent generators in a dictionary with

```py
>>> (eq + x + 2).as_coefficients_dic(x)
{x: 1, x**a*x**b: A + B, 1: 2}
```